# get data from search and make suggestions and show them

Tags: android, search, search-suggestion

I have a search box in action bar and want to show custom suggestion from my data in database.

I read google developer pages about making search and suggestions but each page connects me to a lot of other pages and I confused !!

in other sites there isnt any good tutorial too.

please some one give me here an step by step tutorial about how receive data from serach and then how make suggestions and show them under search.

my second question is that does I have limitation in number of suggestions ?
for example if I returned 100 suggestions android shows all them even with scrollbar ?

Answer (score 0):

try the following example.

row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

img_row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/planet" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView" 
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <Button android:id="@+id/addBtn"
            android:text="Add planet"
            android:onClick="addPlanet"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

PlanetAdapter.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> implements Filterable {

    private List<Planet> planetList;
    private Context context;
    private Filter planetFilter;
    private List<Planet> origPlanetList;

    public PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.img_row_layout, planetList);
        this.planetList = planetList;
        this.context = ctx;
        this.origPlanetList = planetList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return planetList.size();
    }

    public Planet getItem(int position) {
        return planetList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return planetList.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        PlanetHolder holder = new PlanetHolder();

        // First let's verify the convertView is not null
        if (convertView == null) {
            // This a new view we inflate the new layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.img_row_layout, null);
            // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView distView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dist);


            holder.planetNameView = tv;
            holder.distView = distView;

            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else 
            holder = (PlanetHolder) v.getTag();

        Planet p = planetList.get(position);
        holder.planetNameView.setText(p.getName());
        holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());


        return v;
    }

    public void resetData() {
        planetList = origPlanetList;
    }


    /* *********************************
     * We use the holder pattern        
     * It makes the view faster and avoid finding the component
     * **********************************/

    private static class PlanetHolder {
        public TextView planetNameView;
        public TextView distView;
    }



    /*
     * We create our filter 
     */

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (planetFilter == null)
            planetFilter = new PlanetFilter();

        return planetFilter;
    }



    private class PlanetFilter extends Filter {



        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // We implement here the filter logic
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                // No filter implemented we return all the list
                results.values = origPlanetList;
                results.count = origPlanetList.size();
            }
            else {
                // We perform filtering operation
                List<Planet> nPlanetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();

                for (Planet p : planetList) {
                    if (p.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                        nPlanetList.add(p);
                }

                results.values = nPlanetList;
                results.count = nPlanetList.size();

            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {

            // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
            if (results.count == 0)
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            else {
                planetList = (List<Planet>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Planet.java

```
public class Planet {

    private String name;
    private Integer distance;
    private String descr;
    private int idImg;



    public Planet(String name, Integer distance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public Planet(String name, String descr) {
        this.name = name;
        this.descr = descr;
    }

    public Planet(String name, Integer distance, String descr, int idImg) {
        this.name = name;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.descr = descr;
        this.idImg = idImg;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
    public void setDistance(Integer distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
    public int getIdImg() {
        return idImg;
    }
    public void setIdImg(int idImg) {
        this.idImg = idImg;
    }


}
```

Main.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // The data to show
    List<Planet> planetsList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
    PlanetAdapter aAdpt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initList();

        // We get the ListView component from the layout
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


        // This is a simple adapter that accepts as parameter
        // Context
        // Data list
        // The row layout that is used during the row creation
        // The keys used to retrieve the data
        // The View id used to show the data. The key number and the view id must match
        //aAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, planetsList);
        aAdpt = new PlanetAdapter(planetsList, this);
        lv.setAdapter(aAdpt);

        // React to user clicks on item
//        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
//
//          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
//                  long id) {
//              
//              
//              // We know the View is a <extView so we can cast it
//              TextView clickedView = (TextView) view;
//
//              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item with id ["+id+"] - Position ["+position+"] - Planet ["+clickedView.getText()+"]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//          }
//         });

          // we register for the contextmneu        
          registerForContextMenu(lv);

          // TextFilter
          lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
          EditText editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxt);          

          editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    System.out.println("Text ["+s+"] - Start ["+start+"] - Before ["+before+"] - Count ["+count+"]");
                    if (count < before) {
                        // We're deleting char so we need to reset the adapter data
                        aAdpt.resetData();
                    }

                    aAdpt.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
        }


     // We want to create a context Menu when the user long click on an item
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        AdapterContextMenuInfo aInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

        // We know that each row in the adapter is a Map
        Planet planet =  aAdpt.getItem(aInfo.position);

        menu.setHeaderTitle("Options for " + planet.getName());
        menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Details");
        menu.add(1, 2, 2, "Delete");

    }




    // This method is called when user selects an Item in the Context menu
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        AdapterContextMenuInfo aInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        planetsList.remove(aInfo.position);
        aAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }


    private void initList() {
        // We populate the planets

        planetsList.add(new Planet("Mercury", 10));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Venus", 20));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Mars", 30));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Jupiter", 40));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Saturn", 50));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Uranus", 60));
        planetsList.add(new Planet("Neptune", 70));


    }


    // Handle user click
    public void addPlanet(View view) {
        final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        d.setTitle("Add planet");
        d.setCancelable(true);

        final EditText edit = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlanet);
        Button b = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String planetName = edit.getText().toString();
                MainActivity.this.planetsList.add(new Planet(planetName, 0));
                MainActivity.this.aAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged(); // We notify the data model is changed
                d.dismiss();
            }
        });

        d.show();
    }


}
```